# Problems when mapping two values of the same column

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

i concatenated two dataframes , and then tried to map some values in the new DF :
this is the output of my value_counts() on my Survey column in the new DF:

```
  Final_DF['Survey'].value_counts():
  BOUTIQUE          187750
  OUTLET             60468
  CUSTOMER CARE       4781
  E-COMMERCE          2186
  CUSTOMER CARE        269
  False                150
  Name: Survey, dtype: int64
```

(knowing that i've mapped in the same column ***boutique*** with ***BOUTIQUE*** and ***outlet*** with ***OUTLET***) and it worked however , i'm stucked with ***CUStOMER CARE*** , rather than having one value for ***CUSTOMER CARE*** with the sum of the two , i have two ***CUSTOMER CARE*** any idea how to resolve that?

Thank you.

PS : Here's the Output with the ***Unique()*** Function

```
   array(['OUTLET', 'BOUTIQUE', 'CUSTOMER CARE', 'E-COMMERCE', False,
   'CUSTOMER CARE '], dtype=object)
```

Comment: are there spaces in one of them? can you post the results of `Final_DF['Survey'].unique()`

Comment: just did it , Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are spaces in the column as results of `series.unique()` show.

```
array(['OUTLET', 'BOUTIQUE', 'CUSTOMER CARE', 'E-COMMERCE', False,
     'CUSTOMER CARE '], dtype=object)
```

Do a [`strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to get rid of the leading or trailing spaces:

```
Final_DF['Survey']=Final_DF['Survey'].str.strip()
```

Then `value_counts`:

```
Final_DF['Survey'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Indeed , i haven't seen the space !!!! ,  and completely forgot to use unique , thank's again.

Comment: @DouL No problem, happy coding. :) side note, if you are replacing the value, you can call this strip() directly on the replace line